# Issue when transforming an instance of a class to a service ( android / Java )

Tags: java, android

I need to make a change on an old code, the aim is to change a class to a service class :

My issue is that this class contains a static instance of it, this instance is used by all other classes ( More than 30000 lines of code).
So i'am looking for the best way to change it without making lot of changes.

The old class :

```
public class AppManager implements IManagerListener {

    public Activity activity;
    private final Context context;
    public static Storage myDatabase;
    public static final AppManager Instance = new AppManager();
    public final ClientManager client;
    
    private AppManager() {
        client = new ClientManager(SessionManager.getClientID(), SessionManager.getClientStatus());
        client.setListener(this);
        context = getContext();
    }
    
    ...
    
}
```

My change but not working :

```
public class AppManager extends Service implements IManagerListener {

    public Activity activity;
    private  Context context;  // was final
    public static Storage myDatabase;
    public static final AppManager Instance = new AppManager();
    public ClientManager client; // was final
    
    public AppManager() { // was private
        startService(new Intent(this,AppManager.class); // Got Following error here : 
        'android.content.context.startservice(android.content.intent) on a null object reference'
    }
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        client = new ClientManager(SessionManager.getClientID(), SessionManager.getClientStatus());
        client.setListener(this);
        context = getContext();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    ...
    
}
```

Any help, thank you

Comment: Thank you for you answer, the objectif is to start instance as a service, if we can't save static variable as you said as a service, i think i need to look for another solution. thank you again

Comment: Also i'm looking for the simplest way to do it, without making a heavy change to the whole project.